# Building libraries containing CUDA thrust code

Tags: linker, cuda, libraries, thrust, nvcc

With CUDA 5 it is now possible to build libraries containing cuda code and link with nvcc.

Thrust consisting of only header files results in multiple definition errors when linked in this situation.

Is there anyway around this problem without going through and converting thrust to header and code files and building it as a library?

Comment: I'm sure Thrust will be updated to fix this. If you plan on working on getting the definitions out of the headers, maybe you should plan your changes with the authors first, so that any work you do there can be contributed back.

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on the thrust-users mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed on this thrust-users thread, this was indeed a compiler bug. A fix has been made and should be in the [CUDA 5.0 release candidate, which is now available](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit).

Can you please try CUDA 5.0 RC and report back if the issue is fixed?